# Fetching only one row from MySQL using Zend DB framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to fetch only one row from a database because I only expect one. However, with `fetchAll` I always have to unwrap the array first before I can access the meat:

```
$result = self::$db->fetchAll($select);
$result = $result[0];
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also use the `fetchRow` method, i.e.:

```
$result = self::$db->fetchRow($select);
// note that $result is a single object, not an array of objects
```

now you can access column name like this

```
  $myResult = $result->columnName;
```

See
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchrow

Comment: Well, thats even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `fetch` method. Try this:

```
$result = self::$db->query($select)->fetch();
```

**Reference:** http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html#zend.db.statement.fetching.fetch

Comment: `Call to undefined method Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::fetch()`

Comment: Try it now. You have to call `fetch` on a query object, not a database adapter.